# how to return an entity from restful client

Tags: java, rest

I have been into this for days. I am trying to return a persistent entity from a restful web resource using a jersey client. There r two entities in a one to many relation with each other. Everything seem to work just fine but when I get to the part of getting a collection from an entity relationship everything goes burst. While jersey client can lookup XML representations of related entity it does a bad job of getting an entity from a collection of related entity..How do I go about this. Examples will b appreciated. Assume I have a restful web service across the globe and being access by Jersey restful client

Comment: We won't assume anything. This site is meant for you to post specific problems with a complete description and for us to help you fix it.

Comment: Try to come up with a [small example](http://sscce.org/). You will likely find your error while developing it, if not you will have a specific question you can ask here with code example